# How to click by Image in Mobile App by appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator

I need to click on Red Marker location pin shown after searching in Google or EIS Searching Map module in my Mobile App Automation by Appium.

PFB the details for the current workaround I am using but the behaivour for this is not consistent and time consuming wrt to execution time. Can anyone please help in same.Please note that this Pin marked location is not identifiable through UI Automate Viewer.

PFA the screenshot of image in application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define location(x,y coordinates). => `Element.getLocation()`

After than use `driver.tap()` or `Actions.press()`, `longPress()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) for image identification like:

1. [Take screenshot](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/) of the application you're testing
2. Use i.e. [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) algorithm to locate the "Red Marker" at the image and obtain its coordinates
3. Use [TouchActions.press()](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/) function to perform click at the coordinates from step 2

Alternatively you could go for SeeTest Appium Extensions which provide [Image Recognition capabilities](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Image+Recording)